# I have a problem on duplicating a door in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to duplicate my door in unity. but, when I try doing it only the original door is doing the animation like Opening and closing. I have a UI button that uses OnClick function that operates the door. It pops up when I enter the trigger.

[This is the button UI with OnClick function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JSy3.png)

I've tried to make a new UI for each door, but I know that there is a way to make it so that I just need to use one UI for multiple doors. I just don't know how.

```
     private Animator Animatooor;
     public GameObject DoorCollider;
     public GameObject DoorUI;
     public GameObject DoorUICLose;
     void Start()
     {
         Animatooor = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<Animator>();
         Animatooor.SetBool("Open", false);
         DoorCollider.SetActive(true);

     }


     public void Open()
     {
         Animatooor.SetBool("Open", true);

     }
     public void Close()
     {
         Animatooor.SetBool("Open", false);
     }
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hit)
     {
         if (hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
             DoorUI.SetActive(true);
             DoorUICLose.SetActive(true);
         }

     }
     void OnTriggerExit(Collider Hit)
     {
         if (Hit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
             DoorUI.SetActive(false);
             DoorUICLose.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
```

Sorry if I paste all of my code, I just don't know what is the solution on my problem.
I want to duplicate the door and use just the UI button of the original door.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to create two different door animation clip, because each animation instance is only for one gameobject, just try to add second animation clip for second door which will be the same as prevous animation clip

Comment: I have two animation clip which is open and close and I put it in Animation Controller. I already tried making another of it, ut the problem is I need to make new UI button for each door because I used OnClick function. I want to have only one animation controller and one UI button. Is this even possible? Thanks for the reply I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes it is. Just u need to specify which animation clip and which door has to be animated in your onclick method

Comment: Okay, I will try to create another animation clip for different doors. Thank you for your response! It truly helps a lot :)

Comment: The problem: all Animators sharing the **same `AnimatorController`** are always in the **same** state! You would need different AnimatorControllers for each door...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the plus under On Click () there and have another entry just like that, but for the second door.

At the moment this is connected to the Trigge... component instance that is attached to door 1. Door 2 has no idea. Door 2's Trigge... component instance should be similarly notified. Hence the need for the second entry under OnClick here.

Comment: Do I need to make different scripts and animation controller for every door that I duplicate? Sorry, I'm just new in making game in unity.

Comment: I tried making another entry in the OnClick(), but when I do it both the door is animating the same time. I tried making a duplicate of the script and the animation controller ut it has the same result. All of them are now opening and closing at the same time.

Comment: Don't duplicate the script. The same script should be attached on both doors. This creates two separate instances of that script. One script, exists twice on your scene, hence two instances.

Comment: "I tried making another entry in the OnClick(), but when I do it both the door is animating the same time." yes, this was what was supposed to happen. Whichever entry you leave there, that door should open. Whet you have both, both open. Duplicate the button and remove one of the entries, now you have a button for only one door.

Comment: I tried to do what you just told. But when I duplicate the button and remove the other entry it just goes back to the old problem which is the original door is the only one that's animates.

Comment: You are not being careful about which Trigge... is attached there. Click on it once and it will highlight the gameobject.