# Unity Animation for different objects with different time in sequence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple object with same animation behavior. But every animation will start only after the pervious one finish.

How I can do this?

Comment: Your issue sounds related to [I have a problem on duplicating a door in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122246/i-have-a-problem-on-duplicating-a-door-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

You can play around the Unity Animator's Animation States. For example if we have an animation that opens a door called "Open_Door", you can define a transition to a state called "Door_Opened" once it completes. Assuming you have several of doors in your scene and want them to open one after the other, you could achieve this by code by declaring a boolean property that returns the if the state of the animation is finished:

```
bool Door_Opened => yourAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Door_Opened")
```

And using coroutines making sure it is completed before following to the next object.

```
yield return new WaitWhile(() => !Door_Opened);
```